# The DECODE function in some cases returns a number as text?

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

Oracle. SQL. Decode.

Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

I have something funny going on with the DECODE function that I can't figure out and I'm worried about all the queries I've done in the past.

I will try to explain it with an example that I think is the best way to make myself understood.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM (SELECT DECODE((SELECT COUNT(*) 
                         FROM schema.table2 t2
                        WHERE t2.col2 = 2
                          AND t2.col1 = t1.col1), 0, 1, 0) AS num_col2_1,
               DECODE((SELECT COUNT(*) 
                         FROM schema.table2 t2
                        WHERE t2.col2 = 2
                          AND t2.col1 = t1.col1), 0, 0, 1) AS num_col2_2
          FROM schema.table1 t1)        
 WHERE num_col2_1 = 1
```

The result of num_col2_1 and num_col2_2, although inverse, should be the same, but it is not.

Filter by field:

- WHERE numtip1 = 0 -- COUNT(*) = 1 <-- ERROR must be 3
- WHERE numtip1 = 1 -- COUNT(*) = 1  -- result OK
- WHERE numtip2 = 0 -- COUNT(*) = 1  -- result OK
- WHERE numtip2 = 1 -- COUNT(*) = 3  -- result OK
- WHERE numtip1 = '0' -- COUNT(*) = 3  -- result OK
- WHERE numtip1 = '1' -- COUNT(*) = 1  -- result OK
- WHERE numtip2 = '0' -- COUNT(*) = 1  -- result OK
- WHERE numtip2 = '1' -- COUNT(*) = 3  -- result OK

The difference is in the order of the values returned by the DECODE function.

- AND t2.col1 = t1.col1), 0, **1, 0**) AS num_col2_1
- AND t2.col1 = t1.col1), 0, **0, 1**) AS num_col2_2

Oracle DECODE() function syntax
DECODE (e , s1, r1[, s2, r2], ...,[,sn,rn] [, d]);

Return value
The DECODE() function returns a value with **the data type of the first result** (r1, r2, .. rn or d) argument.

the type of the data it returns should not be number?

for num_col2_2 it seems so, but for num_col2_1 it doesn't

- num_col2_1 = '0' -- Result OK <-- why?
- num_col2_1 = '1' -- Result OK <-- why?

I hope I have explained myself well. I would like to understand what is happening or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I dont see why this would be true: "The result of num_col2_1 and num_col2_2, although inverse, should be the same", logic behind decode()  is: `if (select expr) = 0 then 1 else 0` for num_col2_1 column   and    `if (select expr) = 0 then 0 else 1`  for  num_col2_2 column. The decode() result in your case should be number but if it is not nest the decode inside to_number()

Comment: What I have meant with this statement is that if in the first subquery there are 3 records with value 1 and 1 with value 0, in the second subquery there will be 3 records with value 0 and 1 with value 1. But that is not the problem, do not focus on that statement that perhaps what it has done has been to confuse.

Answer (score 0):

Your DECODE statements have the same test condition, but a different default value.
I have coded them below, and run the inner query to show the intermediate result set, which only contains the result set.
If you wish that we should regard the case further please provide the table definitions and sample data that you are working with.

> ```
> SELECT 
>         DECODE((SELECT COUNT(*) 
>                          FROM table2 t2
>                         WHERE t2.col2 = 2
>                           AND t2.col1 = t1.col1), 0, 1, 0) AS num_col2_1,
>         DECODE((SELECT COUNT(*) 
>                          FROM table2 t2
>                         WHERE t2.col2 = 2
>                           AND t2.col1 = t1.col1), 0, 0, 1) AS num_col2_2
>           FROM table1 t1
> ```
>
> ```
> NUM_COL2_1 | NUM_COL2_2
> ---------: | ---------:
>          0 |          1
>          0 |          1
>          0 |          1
>          0 |          1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) 
>   FROM (SELECT DECODE((SELECT COUNT(*) 
>                          FROM table2 t2
>                         WHERE t2.col2 = 2
>                           AND t2.col1 = t1.col1), 0, 1, 0) AS num_col2_1,
>                DECODE((SELECT COUNT(*) 
>                          FROM table2 t2
>                         WHERE t2.col2 = 2
>                           AND t2.col1 = t1.col1), 0, 0, 1) AS num_col2_2
>           FROM table1 t1)        
>  WHERE num_col2_1 = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> | COUNT(*) |
> | -------: |
> |        0 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) 
>   FROM (SELECT DECODE((SELECT COUNT(*) 
>                          FROM table2 t2
>                         WHERE t2.col2 = 2
>                           AND t2.col1 = t1.col1), 0, 1, 0) AS num_col2_1,
>                DECODE((SELECT COUNT(*) 
>                          FROM table2 t2
>                         WHERE t2.col2 = 2
>                           AND t2.col1 = t1.col1), 0, 0, 1) AS num_col2_2
>           FROM table1 t1)        
>  WHERE num_col2_2 = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> | COUNT(*) |
> | -------: |
> |        4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f8a15e5529c775781e289906a085e809)*